# How to convert an incoming JSP page to PDF in MULE?

Tags: mule, itext, mule-studio, mule-component

Details : When i hit a URL it gives me a jsp page which needs to be converted in to a PDF. for now am using ITextPDF in java component for reading the jsp and writing it as PDF. Is there any alternative process within mule without using ITextPDF.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import org.mule.api.MuleEventContext;
import org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable;
import org.mule.api.transport.PropertyScope;

import com.itextpdf.text.Chunk;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
public class PDFConversion implements Callable {

 private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
 StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
 ByteArrayOutputStream bos;
 byte[] result;
 @Override
 public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
     try {

       String productid="";
       String vertical="";
       String postcode="";
       String metertype="";
       String includeSolar="";
       productid=eventContext.getMessage().getInvocationProperty("productId");
       vertical=eventContext.getMessage().getInvocationProperty("vertical");
       postcode=eventContext.getMessage().getInvocationProperty("postcode");
       metertype=eventContext.getMessage().getInvocationProperty("metertype");
       includeSolar=eventContext.getMessage().getInvocationProperty("includeSolar");



         String url = "http://191.111.0.111:****/PDFService/electricitypdf?productid="+productid+"&vertical="+vertical+"&postcode="+postcode+"&metertype="+"&includeSolar="+includeSolar;
         System.out.println(" URL -Request-----"+url);
         URL obj = new URL(url);
         HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
         // optional default is GET
         con.setRequestMethod("GET");
         // add request header
         con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
         int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
         System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
         System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
         String inputLine;
         bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         int next = in.read();
         while (next > -1) {
             bos.write(next);
             next = in.read();
         }
         bos.flush();

/ ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(in); while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) { response.append(inputLine); }/ in.close();

     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

     Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 0.75F, 0.75F, 0.75F, 0.75F);
     document.setPageSize(PageSize.LETTER.rotate());
     // PdfWriter.setPageEvent(new HeaderFooter(mmPDFDocument.right() -
     // mmPDFDocument.left(), footer, path, headerType, unicodeFont));

     PdfWriter.getInstance(document, bos);

     document.open();

     int numberpages=10;
     for (int i = 1; i <= numberpages; i++) 
     {    
                     document.add(new Chunk("Hello PDF Service - Page "+i)); 
                     document.newPage();    
     }        
     FileOutputStream fos= new FileOutputStream("energy.pdf");
     fos.write(bos.toByteArray());
     fos.close();
     document.close();

     return bos;
 }
}
```

Despite writing this the browser is unable to display the content as PDF i could see that the PDF file is being written and when the URL is hit it generates a file of no type(not a pdf). any help appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is basically a standard Java Application running on Mule ESB. Mule is for message based communication and transformations. If you wanted to turn your solution into a full "Mule Solution" I would recommend....

1. Use an http:request directive to call the jsp page to return back html.
    Example here: [Mule ESB : Read HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32791452/mule-esb-read-html)
2. Write a transformer to transform the text/html message to a byte array (or some other type) this will have to be done using ITextPDF.
3. Output the byte array to a file.

You basically are doing the correct steps but not using any advantages of the Mule platform. When you separate the solution out this way you will be able to write the pdf file easily and not get any strange results.